# Windows 10 universal app keyboard alternative

Tags: keyboard, win-universal-app, emoji, custom-keyboard

i have to create a keyboard (layout) or something simular for an universal app. I need an "keyboard" which allows me to show some own Emojies and on pressing adding them (coded) in a Textfield. So like in public Apps like Whatsapp just more basic.

I found just an App for Creating some Layout but i dont think that thats the answer (Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator)

I also found that post (https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/2976742-custom-keyboard-via-code)

So I thought i could make something like an popup which covers the keyboard (on mobile) and in that popup are the emojies. Is this possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with textbox still got focused. Whatsapp and Messenger use the same tactics: you have a emoji button in appbar, when user tap on it, display the popup and remove the focus from text box. By doing so the keyboard disappear. When user tap on a emoji, programmatically add it to the text box. So technically you can not cover the keyboard with anything, but you can simulate the behavior of your input panel to the point it seem as native as the keyboard.

Comment: okay that sounds good. Can you may give me some example code? i also got the problem (or i dont really know how to solve it) to show the emoji-images in the textbox

Comment: to show emoji in textbox, binding / set Text property to the emoji itself, e.g: " ";

Comment: maybe i dont understand what you mean but i actually use some kind of smilie or other icon (codes) in my app. buy my emoji keyboard contains only little pictures (png). But possible u mean the same (so maybe a link of an example - i also would be very happy of an example of an usable popup :s tried some kind but atm its difficult to find some doku for win10 universal apps?)

Comment: Create a popup is not hard, it can be a grid, contains a grid view. Each grid view item will display an emoji. Handle the keyboard showup and close events, put the popup to the right place.

Comment: thanks so far :D i got the pseudo keyboard of the smilies. But now i got the "bigger" problem. Like i asked you in the last comments: how can i now show the emoji in the textbox. I dont rly get it how you wanna bind/set Text property to the emoji itself :s

Comment: something like <TextBlock Text={Binding Emoji}/>

Emoji will be a property of the model, and can have value =  (copy emoji and paste into code)

Comment: i didnt use ascii/text endcoded emojis or something like that. Like i wrote i have to use png. Images in code they are BitmapImage. I also should have that replacement in textblocks. (im building a chat app for your info)